# making a 1D array that contains all the value of a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

the way I did this was:

```
self.cleaned = []
for a in self.P[-1]:
    for b in a:
        for c in b:
            for d in c:
                self.cleaned.extend(d)
```

which is quite ugly and unintuitive, is there a proper way of doing this? maybe using numpy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten directly with numpy using [`np.ndarray.flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy-ndarray-flatten):

```
self.cleaned = np.array(self.P).flatten()
```